# How do I send a collection of objects via angularjs to be created in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a Tournament record that has many Pools. I would like to be able to generate the pools in angularjs, then when the users approves of them, they are sent to the rails backend to be created and saved to the database.

I am having a hard trouble finding a good explanation of how to do this (I suspect I do not know the right language to use in a search).

In Routes.rb

```
resources :tournaments, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
  resources :fencers, only: [:show, :create] do
  end

  resources :pools, only: [:show, :create, :destroy] do
  end

  collection do
    put '/create_pools' => 'pools#create_pools'
  end
end
```

In the pools controller

```
class PoolsController < ApplicationController
  def create_pools
     tournament = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
     tournament.pools.destroy_all # destroy existing pools. 

     params["pools"].each do |p|
       tournament.pools.create(comment_params)
     end

     respond_with tournament, tournament.pools
  end

  private
  def pool_params
    #params.require(:pool).permit(:number, :strip, :fencers)
    params.permit(:pool, array: [:number, :strip, :fencers])
  end
end
```

In an angular service

```
o.savePools = function(id, pools) {
    return $http.post('/tournaments/' + id + '/create_pools.json', pools);
  };
```

I'm pretty confused on how to do a number of aspects of this.
1) How do I get the controller to receive the collection of pools? Does the js need to pass it in like {pools: [pool1, pool2, etc.]} ? and then I would access it via params["pools"]?

2) How do I do strong typing with a collection? I'm not sure what the proper way to strongly type each individual pool in the given collection.

3) If the "fencers" property was itself another object. Are there additional changes I would need for that as well?

Thanks! Please let me know if there is anything I could clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a .net developer but maybe a general advice can become useful for this problem.

In ASP.Net MVC, if I post a collection like the following code, it automatically bind it for me to a typed list. please notice how pools is passed in the parameter object.

```
o.savePools = function(id, pools) {
    return $http.post('/tournaments/' + id + '/create_pools.json', { "pools": pools });
  };
```

If I didn't have .net's magical binding, then I would send the serialized string of the pools, and then in the server side (Your case Ruby side), I would deserialized that string

```
o.savePools = function(id, pools) {
    return $http.post('/tournaments/' + id + '/create_pools.json', { "poolsJson": JSON.stringify(pools) });
  };
```

Good luck!